# Postgres search by part of word

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a question about fts( full text search). I’m using GIN index for search into my database. But i have problem with searching by part of word. Please advice to me how i can get this kind of search.

Comment: You could use `LIKE`?

Comment: With GIN and vectors I have to much goodness. Like column weight, speed, multi columns search

Comment: I need the same like I using now, but with part of word. I can’t find some thing in documentation. Maybe I missed some?

Comment: "I need the same like I using now"  You haven't described what you are using now in any detail.  Please show example queries of what you are doing now and what you would like to do instead.